# Are LINK elements loaded synchronously?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, onload, synchronous

If I have the following HTML5 document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FOOBAR</title>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/largefonts.css">
<script src="onload.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Will the `<link>` tag load synchronously, so that when the `onload.js` script is executed, the fonts should be loaded in the browser?

Note that I’m not asking if the fonts have been **applied** to any DOM nodes, I just want to know if they are loaded into memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process for obtaining `<link>` resources is described in the [corresponding section of the HTML5 spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#concept-link-obtain), and answers like this:

> User agents **may** opt to only try to obtain such resources when they are needed, instead of pro-actively fetching all the external resources that are not applied

However,

> The [`<link>`] element must delay the load event of the element's document until all the attempts to obtain the resource and its critical subresources are complete

…meaning that a document's `load` event won't fire until all `<link>`s have been loaded (or failed)

Comment: So in other words, no there is no guarantee that it is, but in a domReady or window.onload event it should be loaded/failed, right?