# Will flash of unstyled content (FOUC) occur if link tags are in the head?

Tags: html, css, fouc

My understanding is that the link tag is synchronous: [Are LINK elements loaded synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371080/are-link-elements-loaded-synchronously)

If so, FOUC should only be a problem for CSS that is in link tags below some content. Is that true?

Comment: Seems vendor specific and/or non-deterministic given the answers on the other question you found.

Comment: One case where a FOUC can still occur if the link tags are in the head (at least in Firefox), is if you load a JS library such as modernizr before the link tags.